# Java Apache POI 3.7 XWPFTable cell color Change

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi

I'm trying to create a table in word document using Java Apache POI 3.7 and I need  to change the cell color of  that table. I use XWPFTable  but there are no way to change the cell color .Can anybody suggest a hack to do it?

```
    XWPFTable tableVersion = document.createTable(); 
    XWPFTableRow tableOneRowVersion = tableVersion.createRow();
    tableOneRowVersion.getCell(0).setText("Version");
```

Answer (score 3):

Ref : https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFTableCell.html

For Example:

```
XWPFTable tableVersion = document.createTable(); 
XWPFTableRow tableOneRowVersion = tableVersion.createRow();
tableOneRowVersion.getCell(0).setColor("000000");
tableOneRowVersion.getCell(0).setText("Version");
```

Make sure that you set the color in a hexa decimal form...